# Array of objects in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am a JS newbi am trying to create an Array of objects.
I have created the following object:

```
gameCard = new Object({
    image : "",
    container:"",
    match2Card:"",
    visible: false,
    cardId:"",

    updateCard: function (imageName,divName,matchingCard,isVisible,cardId) {
        this.image = imageName;
        this.container = divName;
        this.match2Card = matchingCard;
        this.visible = isVisible;
        this.cardId = cardId;
    },
    toggleCard: function (){
        if (this.visble) {
            this.visble = false;
        }
        else {
            this.visble = true;
        }
    },
    printCard : function() {
        document.write (this.image + ' ' + this.container + ' ' + this.match2Card + ' ' + this.visible + ' ' + this.cardId + '<br>') ;
        //alert (this.match2card);
    }
})
```

and run the following :

```
gameCards = new Array ();

for (i=0; i<20 ; i=i+1) {
    z=i+1;

    c1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+1);

    gameCard.updateCard ( 'images/bf'+i+'.jpg' , 'div' + c1 , z , false,i) ;

    gameCards.push(gameCard);
}
```

when printing the array by using :

```
for (i=0;i<20; i++) {
    gameCards[i].printCard();
}
```

all items are the same.

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Use Object literal form **{}** instead of **new Object()** and same for Array [] instead of new Array()

Comment: Can it be you are updating the same instance all the time?

Comment: You're only creating one card and then adding it to the array over and over.  You need to create multiple card instances inside your loop.

Comment: @PointedEars Yes, you're right with for loop it's just creating 20 pointer for same  object

Comment: @Givi Afterwards the array contains 20 _references to_ the same object.

Answer (score 1):

You are using only one object, you must use

`gameCard = {…}` in the loop. (new Object is not necessary)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
   var gameCard = {…}; // create a new instance of object
   …
}
```

Comment: The `Object` constructor does not use its argument for initialization; it converts it into an object. Therefore the `Object` constructor is unnecessary here; the object initialiser `{…}` already creates an `Object` instance and evaluates to a reference to that instance.

Comment: @PointedEars Yes, but the important is to create a new instance in the loop

Comment: @PointedEars what?  this answer looks right to me.  If there's a further mistake the OP made, this answer covers the most important one.

Comment: @djechlin It looks right *now*. You are falsely assuming that I downvoted it.

Comment: @PointedEars why does it look right now?  The `var` decl didn't matter.

Comment: @djechlin It did, and so did the missing semicolon. RTFM.

Comment: @PointedEars would you mind explaining why?  Semicolons are optional in JS and I believe so are `var` declarations in most cases.

Comment: @djechlin Yes, I would mind. This is not JavaScript 101, I have explained the issue many times before, and the *full* explanation would not fit into this comment box anyway. Please view the edit history of this answer and read a *decent* tutorial on ECMAScript and its implementations. Try [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript) for a start.

Comment: @PointedEars would you mind linking to an answer in which you explain this issue or a relevant section on MDN?

Comment: @djechlin Hate to interject in such a spirited debacle. `var` is indeed optional - but bear in mind that omitting `var` implicitly creates a variable in global scope which in 99.9% of circumstances is not what you will want. The risk is in that it will conflict with similarly declared variables elsewhere, amongst other unpleasant side effects.

Comment: @djechlin This really is basic knowledge. One of my more recent postings on the subject is archived at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!original/comp.lang.javascript/iekkNGj6SYA/IoKuhV-anT8J.  Which also shows that simply omitting `var` in an assignment does *not* create a variable *at all*; it creates – in the *best* case – a user-defined *deletable* *property* of the ECMAScript Global Object.

Comment: @PointedEars ..known to everyone else as a variable :)

Comment: @ElRonnoco Can't you read? Try `var x = 42; delete x; x` vs. `y = 42; delete y; y`. Realize the difference. And have an element with ID `y` and see the second *assignment* *fail* already in IE/MSHTML.

Comment: @PointedEars Yes I can read, thank you for your concern. I understand the difference. What I am saying is that for most purposes you can do anything with a `var` that you can do with a 'property of the ECMAScript Global Object' - I think given the OP's apparent JS level then my explanation will be more enlightening (although maybe not *100%* accurate) than your somewhat rude declamations.

Comment: @ElRonnoco A variable *can be* a property, but a property is *not* a variable. It is important to understand the difference, *especially* for a beginner, as I have showed. It is *your* problem that you do not understand that.

Answer (score 1):

Either define your `GameCard` object like so (**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLjEC/)**):

```
var GameCard = function () { //wrap in a function to mimic a constructor
    return {
        "image": "",
        "container": "",
        "match2Card": "",
        "visible": false,
        "cardId": "",
        "updateCard": function (imageName, divName, matchingCard, isVisible, cardId) {
            this.image = imageName;
            this.container = divName;
            this.match2Card = matchingCard;
            this.visible = isVisible;
            this.cardId = cardId;
        },
        "toggleCard": function () {
            this.visible = !this.visible;
        },
        "printCard": function () {
            log(this.image + ' ' + this.container + ' ' + this.match2Card + ' ' + this.visible + ' ' + this.cardId + '<br>');
        }
    };
};

var test = function () {
    var gameCards = [],
        card = null,
        i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i = i + 1) {
        // call the function to get a new object
        card = GameCard();
        // set object properties
        z = i + 1;
        c1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
        card.updateCard('images/bf' + i + '.jpg', 'div' + c1, z, false, i);
        // push into array
        gameCards.push(card);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        gameCards[i].printCard();
    }
};
test();
```

or define it like this (**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLjEC/1/)**):

```
var GameCard = function () { //or make a constructable object
    this.image = "";
    this.container = "";
    this.match2Card = "";
    this.visible = false;
    this.cardId = "";
    this.updateCard = function (imageName, divName, matchingCard, isVisible, cardId) {
        this.image = imageName;
        this.container = divName;
        this.match2Card = matchingCard;
        this.visible = isVisible;
        this.cardId = cardId;
    };
    this.toggleCard = function () {
        this.visible = !this.visible;
    };
    this.printCard = function () {
        log(this.image + ' ' + this.container + ' ' + this.match2Card + ' ' + this.visible + ' ' + this.cardId + '<br>');
    };
};

var test = function () {
    var gameCards = [],
        card = null,
        i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i = i + 1) {
        // instantiate new object
        card = new GameCard();
        // set properties
        z = i + 1;
        c1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
        card.updateCard('images/bf' + i + '.jpg', 'div' + c1, z, false, i);
        // push into array
        gameCards.push(card);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        gameCards[i].printCard();
    }
};
test();
```

Otherwise, what you're doing is pushing the same instance into the array 20 times.

**UPDATE**

You could also define your `GameCard` object as you're currently doing and then call `Object.create(GameCard)` to create a new instance of it (**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLjEC/3/)**):

```
var GameCard = {
    "image": "",
    "container": "",
    "match2Card": "",
    "visible": false,
    "cardId": "",
    "updateCard": function (imageName, divName, matchingCard, isVisible, cardId) {
        this.image = imageName;
        this.container = divName;
        this.match2Card = matchingCard;
        this.visible = isVisible;
        this.cardId = cardId;
    },
    "toggleCard": function () {
        this.visible = !this.visible;
    },
    "printCard": function () {
        log(this.image + ' ' + this.container + ' ' + this.match2Card + ' ' + this.visible + ' ' + this.cardId + '<br>');
    };

var test = function () {
    var gameCards = [],
        card = null,
        i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i = i + 1) {
        // use Object.create for a constructor
        card = Object.create(GameCard);
        // set properties
        z = i + 1;
        c1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
        card.updateCard('images/bf' + i + '.jpg', 'div' + c1, z, false, i);
        // push into array
        gameCards.push(card);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        gameCards[i].printCard();
    }
};
test();
```

Comment: Using a function as constructor that does not have prototype methods or properties to return an object is needlessly complicated, except when you use closures (have “private properties” in the constructor).

Comment: thx you all for you help am going to check what you suggested and will update if I was able to solve this issue.

Comment: am still getting the same result :( I wanted create an Array that will include 20 items of the object gameCard (should have beed 20 different item and sill getting the same items 20 items. I have tried to use gamesCards[i] = new object (gameCard); but it did not help

Comment: @user2463457: I minimized the code needed for the answer. Check out the included (and working) jsFiddles and compare those with your code.

Comment: when running the updated fiddle am getting the same issue that am currently handling all the Items in the Array are having the same value.

Comment: @user2463457: Updated answer to better reflect fiddles (which are tested and functional in Chrome). What browser are you using?

Comment: am using Chrome, when running this http://jsfiddle.net/wLjEC/2/ am getting that all the items are the same unlike the 2 first fiddle you uploaded.

Comment: @user2463457: My mistake. Updated answer and fiddle for the last portion. I should have used `Object.create(GameCard);` instead of `new Object(GameCard);` (a momentary lapse in memory and reason whereupon I mistakenly thought that `new Object()` would accept a parameter for a constructor).